# Warning: Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`Duck`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Duck`

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-hooks

I am fairly new to React and was working on a silly site where a randomly selected duck will randomly spawn on the webpage each time you click the summon duck button. The more you click, the more ducks there are.

I have ran into the issues stated in the title and I am having a hard time figuring out where the issue is coming from besides the hint that it is in the Duck.js file.

Here is the error message if it helps:
[The error message of Warning: Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`Duck`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Duck`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
at Duck (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/componentsTESTING/Duck.js:31:9)
at div
at SummonDuckWrapper (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/componentsTESTING/SummonDuckWrapper.js:17:78)
at main
at Home
at StaticGenerationSearchParamsBailoutProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyCOV.png)

Here is my code below

```
export const SummonDuckWrapper = () => {
    const [ducks, setDucks] = useState([])

    const addDuck = (duck, picture) => {
        setDucks([...ducks, {location: duck, duckPic: picture}])
    }
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(ducks)
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <SummonDuckButton addDuck={addDuck}/>
      {ducks.map((duck, duckPic, index) => (
        <Duck location={duck} picture={duckPic} key={index}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SummonDuckWrapper
```

```
export const SummonDuckButton = ({ addDuck, duckImage }) => {
    const [left, setLeft] = useState(0);
    const [top, setTop] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLeft((Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.width)))
        setTop(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.height))
    }, [])

    const location = {
        left: left + 'px',
        top: top + 'px'
    }

    const summonDuck = () => {
        setLeft(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.width));
        setTop(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.height));
        const randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        
        addDuck(location, randomImage)
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={summonDuck} className='I removed this so it'll be easier to read'>
            Summon Duck
        </button>
    )
}

export default SummonDuckButton
```

The problem child

```
const images = [
    //these are SVGs that I imported
    <DuckFamily />,
    <DuckOne />,
    <DuckTwo />
];

const Duck = () => {
    const thePicture = images[{ picture }]
    return (
        <div style={location}>
            <img src={thePicture} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Duck
```

Currently, I am trying to get a random position in the array of duck svgs to be randomly placed on the screen. I had this working before with a call to another component that returned a RandomDuck but it caused the ducks to changed each time you summoned a duck.

Let me know what you thinK! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: first of all your sample code is incomplete and invalid e.g. the Duck but I think you have a rerender of the component hosting the ducks list state thus the button that triggers the change is rerendered during the state update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH I was not able to replicate, you may want to provide a code that can be reproducible, however you can try with the following adjustements to your code:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import SummonDuckButton from './SummonDuckButton';
import Duck from './Duck';

let duckId = 0;
export const SummonDuckWrapper = () => {
  const [ducks, setDucks] = useState([]);

  const addDuck = useCallback(
    (duck, picture) => {
      setDucks([...ducks, { location: duck, duckPic: picture, id: duckId++ }]);
    },
    [ducks]
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ducks);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <SummonDuckButton addDuck={addDuck} />
      {ducks.map(({ duck, duckPic, id }) => (
        <Duck location={duck} picture={duckPic} key={id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SummonDuckWrapper;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const SummonDuckButton = ({ addDuck, duckImage }) => {
  const { screen } = window;
  const [left, setLeft] = useState(0);
  const [top, setTop] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLeft(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.width));
    setTop(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.height));
  }, [screen.height, screen.width]);

  const location = {
    left: left + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
  };

  const summonDuck = () => {
    setLeft(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.width));
    setTop(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.height));
    const randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    addDuck(location, randomImage);
  };

  return (
    <button
      onClick={summonDuck}
      className="I removed this so it'll be easier to read"
    >
      Summon Duck
    </button>
  );
};

export default SummonDuckButton;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const images = [
  //these are SVGs that I imported
  <DuckFamily />,
  <DuckOne />,
  <DuckTwo />,
];

const Duck = ({ picture, location }) => {
  const thePicture = images[picture];
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{thePicture}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Duck;
```

It hasnt throw any errors for me

Comment: That helped! Had to change things around to get it to work but it has helped!

Comment: There's no summary of fixes in the answer so I compared the code. It looks like you did two things to fix the issue: add a `useCallback` hook on `addDuck`, and ensure the `useEffect` setting position has the correct dependency array. Is that all?